# Continuously rotate image centered on background

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to continuously rotate an image or series of images and output as a video with `ffmpeg`? Rotating image should be centered over a background.

See [example video](https://youtu.be/jN3J5ZVoDps?t=15).

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation. Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN3J5ZVoDps from a static image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [rotate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) filter to rotate the image, the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) filter as a background, the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter to place image over background, and the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to ensure widely compatible chroma subsampling for H.264 video.

[image: example of rotating image over plain background]

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=00ff00:s=1280x720:d=10 -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1]rotate=angle=PI*t:fillcolor=none:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[fg];[0][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

The speed is controlled by the [rotate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) filter: specifically the `angle` parameter. Examples:

- 90 degrees clockwise per second: `angle=90*PI/180*t`
- 1 degree clockwise per frame: `angle=PI/180*n`
- 1 complete rotation (2 radians) per second counter-clockwise: `angle=-2*PI*t`

See the [rotate filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) for more examples.

If you want GIF instead of MP4 see [How do I output GIF using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/556031)

Comment: You, my friend - are a genius!

Comment: Could you set the speed?for example if I woould like to make it slower?

Comment: @user467801 I added some more examples. See updated answer.